# SQL Server 2008 log issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. Under logs folder, in my machine it is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log, there are three kinds of files,

```
•ERRORLOG, ERRORLOG.1, ERRORLOG.2 ...    ERRORLOG.6;
•FDLAUNCHERRORLOG,    FDLAUNCHERRORLOG.1, FDLAUNCHERRORLOG.2,    ...FDLAUNCHERRORLOG.6;
•log_207.trc, log_208.trc, ...
```

My question is what are the differnet function of such log files? And why there are files ends with .1, .2, etc?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ERRORLOG` files are just what they sound like - logs of errors that happen within your SQL server. When you are in SQL Management Studio, if you look at the "SQL Server Logs" it is viewing the `ERRORLOG`. The files with numbers at the end are archived log files when it rotates.

The `FDLAUNCHERRORLOG` files are for errors that occur in the SQL Server Full Text Filter Daemon launcher service. This is a separate service used to load filters for full text search. Again, the files with numbers are archived files after log rotation.

The `.TRC` files are SQL Profiler traces. SQL 2008 does some default tracing to help troubleshoot issues.